# $3y''+4y'+y=sin(t)e^{-t}, y(0)=1 y'(0)=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I can get that the two solutions are $e^{\frac{-t}{3}}$ and $e^{-t}$ but am getting integrals that don't work out when I calculate $u_1$ and $u_2$.

For $W[y_1,y_2](t)$ I am getting

$-e^{\frac{4t}{3}}+\frac{e^{-2t/3}}{3}$, which I don't think is right since this shouldn't be a complex problem.

Any help please would be appreciated.

Comment: Actually these type of problems without a constant coefficient can be nasty to solve, but regardless of what method you choose, laplace transform, variation of parameters, or method of undetermined coefficients, the answers should be the same. It's just that some methods are better than others, but requires a truckload of work. Feel free to look at my ODE questions and you'll see one method where I had to expand a function and take massive derivatives.

Answer (score 1):

For the homogeneous case, $3u''(t)+4u'(t)+u(t)=0$, the general solution is ($C_1$ and $C_2$ arbitrary constants):
$$ u(t)=C_1e^{-t/3}+C_2e^{-t}$$
Now for the inhomogeneous case $3v''(t)+4v'(t)+v(t)=\sin(t)e^{-t}$, guess a solution of the form $e^{-t}(A\cos(t)+B\sin(t))$, with $A, B$ constants, and work out $A$ and $B$ by differentiating and using the differential equation. You will find $A=\frac{2}{13}$ and $B=-\frac{3}{13}$ and hence the particular solution:
$$v(t)=\frac{1}{13}e^{-t}(2\cos(t)-3\sin(t))$$
It follows that the general solution to the differential equation is:
$$y(t)=C_1e^{-t/3}+C_2e^{-t}+\frac{1}{13}e^{-t}(2\cos(t)-3\sin(t))$$
Now fill in the initial values to determine the constants $C_1$ and $C_2$ to be $\frac{24}{13}$ and $-1$ respectively. So the final answer is:
$$y(t)=\frac{24}{13}e^{-t/3}-e^{-t}+\frac{1}{13}e^{-t}(2\cos(t)-3\sin(t))$$

Comment: How do you find A and B? I'm a little confused, my prof never showed us this form. Thanks for the help

Comment: You fill in $ v (t) = e^{-t}(A\cos(t)+B\sin (t)) $ into the differential equation. On the left hand side you will get terms $e^{-t}\cos (t) $ and $ e^{-t}\sin (t) $ with factors involving $ A $ and $ B $ in front. Now we want the factor of the $\cos $ term to be zero and the factor of the $\sin $ term to be one to match the right hand side.  Now from these two equations you can determine what $ A $ and $ B $ should be.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that by $W[y_1,y_2]$ you mean the Wronskian.  It should be
$$\det\pmatrix{e^{-t/3}&e^{-t}\cr -\frac13e^{-t/3}&-e^{-t}\cr}
  =-\frac23e^{-4t/3}\ .$$